# Ошибка в программе при запуске компьютера: System.UnauthorizedAccess

Tags: c#

Есть программа, находится в автозагрузке. При запуске компьютера программа вылетает с ошибкой System.Unauthorized Accetss. Программа изначально создает папку(в автозагрузке), в конце удаляет ее. Поискав наткнулся только на то, что проблема именно в создании папки(как раз перед ошибкой она у меня не создается), но решения проблемы не нашел. Буду благодарен развернутому ответу с решением.

Comment: а вы гуглить не пробовали?

Comment: Развернутого ответа не получится: нужно больше деталей. Могу лишь предположить, что создание папки требует прав администратора, которых у программы нет.

Comment: @Shad дело в том, что программа все отрабатывает правильно, если запускать ее вручную(без админа), но запустившись после включения компьютера, вылетает.

Comment: А в System.UnauthorizedAccess.Message что-нибудь содержится? А папка в автозагрузке это где? В реестре?

Answer (score 1):

Я разобрался с этой проблемой. Как оказалось, приложения со стартапа могут использовать специальную директорию, для создаваемых ими папок и файлов.

```
public string appdata = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

У меня в appdata запишется C:\Users\Alex2\AppData\Roaming
И именно в ней я могу создавать директории и файлы.