# Ошибка при автозагрузке

Tags: c#

Сделал автозагрузку приложения на C#. Всё было нормально. Добавил в программу дерево каталогов. После этого при автозагрузке программы выдаёт ошибку "Программа WindowsFormsApplication1 прекратила свою работу."

```
   private void PopulateTreeView()
        {
            TreeNode rootNode;

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(@"../..");
            if (info.Exists)
            {
                rootNode = new TreeNode(info.Name);
                rootNode.Tag = info;
                GetDirectories(info.GetDirectories(), rootNode);
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
            }
        }

        private void GetDirectories(DirectoryInfo[] subDirs,
   TreeNode nodeToAddTo)
        {
            TreeNode aNode;
            DirectoryInfo[] subSubDirs;
            foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in subDirs)
            {
                aNode = new TreeNode(subDir.Name, 0, 0);
                aNode.Tag = subDir;
                aNode.ImageKey = "folder";
                subSubDirs = subDir.GetDirectories();
                if (subSubDirs.Length != 0)
                {
                    GetDirectories(subSubDirs, aNode);
                }
                nodeToAddTo.Nodes.Add(aNode);
            }
        }

        private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeNode newSelected = e.Node;
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            DirectoryInfo nodeDirInfo = (DirectoryInfo)newSelected.Tag;
            ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[] subItems;
            ListViewItem item = null;

            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in nodeDirInfo.GetDirectories())
            {
                item = new ListViewItem(dir.Name, 0);
                subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
                  {new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "Directory"), 
                   new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, 
                dir.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())};
                item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
            foreach (FileInfo file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                item = new ListViewItem(file.Name, 1);
                subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
                  { new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "File"), 
                   new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, 
                file.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())};

                item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }

            listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
            this.treeView1.NodeMouseClick +=
    new TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler(this.treeView1_NodeMouseClick);
        }

    }
```

Вот код дерева каталогов.

```
 public bool SetAutorun(bool autorun)
        {
            string ExePath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath;
            RegistryKey reg;
            reg = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\");
            try
            {
                if (autorun)
                {
                    reg.SetValue(ProgrammName, ExePath);

                }
                else
                    reg.DeleteValue(ProgrammName);

                reg.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        private void button25_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool autorun = SetAutorun(true);

        }

        private void button26_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           bool Autorun = SetAutorun(false);


        }
```

Вот код добавления в автозагрузку.

Comment: Нужно посмотреть какое исключение кидает программа. Можете отлавливать все необработанные исключения и писать их в лог.  Как это сделать написано тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547258/Обработка-необработанных-исключений

Comment: Под отладчиком запускать пробовали?

Comment: С отладкой всё норм, работает.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то выкидывает исключение System.UnauthorizedAccess. В exe файле поставил запуск от имени администратора, но всё равно ошибка.

Comment: @Андрей Если ваша программа при загрузке пытается создать или удалить папку/файл, то вам все это надо делать в %AppData%. тут похожая проблема http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/313706/Ошибка-в-программе-при-запуске-компьютера-system-unauthorizedaccess